# Jquery .mouseover() not working (catch me)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing homework jquery, I tried to add more to mouseover but it doesn't work

```js
$("button").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).css({
    left: (Math.random() * 300) + "px",
    top: (Math.random() * 300) + "px",
  }, 1);
});
```

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  left: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h1>Catch me if you can !</h1> 
  <div class="main"></div>
  <button>
    <img src="cat/grey-cat-001.gif">
  </button>
</body>
```

Comment: show us your failed effort.

Comment: what is your code which you have tried?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
     $("button").mouseover(function(){
         $(this).css({
        left:(Math.random()*300)+"px",
        top:(Math.random()*300)+"px",
    },1);
});

Comment: <body>
<div class ="main"> </div>
 <button><img src="cat/grey-cat-001.gif"></button>
</body>

Comment: @TtVox Please edit your question and add your code/html there.

Comment: when the mouse cursor on the image, it does not move random. @@Prakash Laxkar

Answer (score 1):

It's because the default `position` for every element is `static` which won't take any effect from `top`, `left`, `right`, or `bottom` style.

> HTML elements are positioned static by default.
>
> Static positioned elements are not affected by the top, bottom, left, and right properties.

so what you need is just to add `position: relative` or `position: absolute` for the button like in this snippet:

```js
$("button").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).css({
    left: (Math.random() * 300) + "px",
    top: (Math.random() * 300) + "px",
  }, 1);
});
```

```css
button {
  position: relative;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="main"></div>
  <button>
    <img src="cat/grey-cat-001.gif">
  </button>
</body>
```

Comment: body{
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
 margin: 100px auto;
}
div.main{
 background-color: #ff6;
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

button{
   position: relative;  
}
h1{
 text-align: center;
 font-family:Brush Script Std;
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $("button").mouseover(function(){
         $(this).css({
        left:(Math.random()*300)+"px",
        top:(Math.random()*300)+"px",
    },1);
});
</script>

<body>
<h1>Catch me if you can !</h1>
<div class ="main"> </div>
 <button> <img src="cat/grey-cat-001.gif"></button>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @TtVox, is it still not working in your side? Are you sure you have included the `jQuery` in your page? This line of code `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` in the `<head>` or `<body>`. You can also check the `Developer Tools` by pressing `F12` and see if there's any error there.

Comment: yes, I checked with the jquery. I run in eclipse. I do not understand why not run on my code.

Comment: @TtVox are there any `error` in the `Developer Tools`? If you're using Chrome, press `F12` then go to `Console` tab. If there are any error, copy the error here

Comment: thanks @Kyojimaru . this error : Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @TtVox, that means that when the `mouseover` is being called, the `jQuery` isn't there yet. Make sure you include the `jQuery` first before you call a function that use it, like this: `... <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script‌​><script>$("button").mouseover(function() {...`. If it's still not working, try to change the `$` to `jQuery`.

Comment: I had her tied changing place, now say no errors but it also does not have to run when the mouse moves. I do not know the cause is nothing.

Comment: @TtVox, join [https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90189/jquery-mouseover-not-working-catch-me](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90189/jquery-mouseover-not-working-catch-me) for the continuation